# jquery - any way to hide any class that is less than 3? for instance

Tags: jquery

I want to have a bunch of spans with classes of different "depths", i.e one may be depth 1, another depth 2, another depth 3.

```
<span class="depth1"></span>
<span class="depth2"></span>
<span class="depth3"></span>
```

Then, if I want to hide anything that's below depth 3, I don't know how else to do it besides a for loop

```
for (i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
  $(".depth" + i).hide();
```

Is there any better way to do this? maybe class ="3" instead of "depth3"? And any way to allow floating points, so that 2.5 and 1.5 will both be hidden too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("span").each(function(){
    var depth = $(this).attr("class").split("-");
    if (depth[1]<3) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: You need to get the class, not the id.

Comment: this won't work if there the spans have multiple classnames though

Answer (score 4):

Don't pollute your markup with useless classes when there is a better way to go.

If your `<span>`s are within the same parent element, as such:

```
<div class="spancontainer">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

You can hide the first two `<span>` with the [**`:lt(index)`**](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/lt#index) pseudo-selector:

```
$('.spancontainer span:lt(2)').hide();
```

If your `<span>`s are not within the same parent element, simply assign them a special class as such:

```
<div>
  <span class="depth"></span>
  <span class="depth"></span>
  <span class="depth"></span>
</div> 
<span class="depth"></span>
<span class="depth"></span>
```

Then, you can still hide the first two `<span>` by using the [**`:lt(index)`**](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/lt#index) pseudo-selector:

```
$('span.depth:lt(2)').hide();
```

Using this approach makes your code more maintainable (no need to keep track of index to insert or delete), wastes less bytes (it is important when you are on dailup) and is generally cleaner.

---

**EDIT:** And if you are trying to display a tree-like structure, you are better of using nested tags instead of your current markup.

Comment: Only 21.9 % broadband penetration in the US, 23.7 % in Canada.

Comment: Why did I deserve a -1? Because I suggested another/better way of implementing the same thing?

Comment: this will not work if the OP has his spans as listed in the question, denoted only by the number in the class and all in a row. he would have to separate them some other way. if the OP doesn't have access to the markup, your solution won't work.

Comment: **Jason:** `$('span[class*=depth]:lt(2)').hide()` will work if the OP doesn't have access to the markup.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of improvements to Jason's solution.

```
$('span[class*=depth]').each(function() {

    var matches = $(this).attr('class').match(/(^|\s)depth(\d+(.\d+)?)/);

    // matches[0] has the whole match
    // matches[1] has either empty string (beginning of the string) or a space
    // matches[2] has the actual depth value (with fracture part if present)
    // matches[3] has the fracture part of the depth name

    if (matches[2] !== undefined && matches[2] < 3) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Improvements:

- the selector will filter all span's that doesn't have `depth` keyword in their class attribute (this won't prevent from matching class names like `mydepth`, `depthtest` but these are filtered by in the next step)
- this will match floating point depths as well (although I'm not sure if `depth1.5` is a correct class name)
- this will work ok if you have more then just `depth*` class defined for element

Answer (score 0):

For doing it with enumerated class names, I would create a "*range*" function, to generate a vaild selector:

```
function range(start, end, prependText){
  var result = [];
  for (var i = start; i < start + end; i++){
    var element = (prependText||'') + i;
    result.push(element);
  }
  return result.join();
}

var mySelector = range(1,3,'.depth'); // will return ".depth1,.depth2,.depth3"
//...
                 range(3,3,'.depth'); // returns ".depth3,.depth4,.depth5"
```

It will return a valid [multiple selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/multiple) that you can use to match the elements.

Another approach I think you might can use is the less than selector ([lt](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/lt#index)), this selector matches elements based on its index:

```
$("span:lt(3)") // will match the first three spans, with index 0, 1, and 2
```

If your span elements are contained in other parent element, you can use this selector like [this](http://jsbin.com/idobu):

```
$('#container span:lt(3)') // match the first three span childs of the container element
```